# Subtracting Dates using Java Calendar

Tags: java, date, calendar, date-arithmetic

I have 2 Calendar objects for the current date and birthdate.
I need to subtract birthdate from the current date and return the difference in years (a truncated Int is all I need).

What's the simplest way of doing this?

Comment: Just subtract the two years... simple enough. Look at the calendar class https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html   `HINT: As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by Calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1900`

Comment: @But with your example I'd only be subtracting from the year, not the entire date.

Comment: You said you need the difference in years....

Comment: @3kings, Ahhh I meant the result would be in years.

Comment: @MartinRand Please search Stack Overflow before posting. Virtually all the basic date-time questions have already been asked and answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can get EPOCH time (miliseconds since 01.01.1900), subtract both values and divide it by `1000(miliseconds)/60(seconds)/60(minutes)/24(hours)/365(days)`.
This would give you approximate result (in years) because of ignoring leap years.

To get epoch time, use `Date#getTime()`;

Comment: This approach would be ignoring much more than leap years. It would ignore Daylight Saving Time and all the other anomalies captured in the definition of a time zone.

Comment: Isnt EPOCH in UTC ?.